# I want to find a word(Including special characters) match in a sentence using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried using the below code.

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + wordToMatch + "\\b", 'i'),
    wordToMatch = '$10',
    sentenseToSearch = "That book costs $10."
sentenseToSearch.match(regex);
```

It works if wordtoMatch = 'book' or 'That' or 'costs' and failed to match when wordToMatch is "$10".
Same issue with apostrophe (') character.

Ex:-

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + wordToMatch + "\\b", 'i'),
    wordToMatch = 'Edward',
    sentenseToSearch = "He is Edward's father."
sentenseToSearch.match(regex);
```

Above code should result null as the sentence doesn't have Edward in it.
But it is matching the Edward's text excluding the 's characters.

My code works good for all the words except for the words including special characters like ($,', - etc)..
Could someone help me providing the regex to match words including the special characters.

Comment: Note that sentence is spelled as `sentence` - you might fix that to avoid bugs in the future

Comment: Try https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#escapeRegExp

Comment: It has already been mentioned that you have to escape the strings properly. Another problem in your first example will be that the combination of the boundary symbol \b directly followed by a dollar sign (or other special characters) will not work. You have to find a workaround as \b only finds alphanumeric word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping user input that is to be treated as a literal string within a regular expression—that would otherwise be mistaken for a special character—can be accomplished by simple replacement:

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}
```

Test code:

```js
function escapeRegExp(string) {
      return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}

var wordToMatch = '$10';
var sentenseToSearch = "That book costs $10.";
var regex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(wordToMatch), 'i');
alert(sentenseToSearch.match(regex));
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help. Your code is working for $10 case but failing in the 2nd case. Code is given below. Could you please check it out.

var wordToMatch = 'Edward',
      regex = new RegExp("\\b" + wordToMatch + "\\b", 'i'),
    
    sentenseToSearch = "He is Edward's father."
sentenseToSearch.match(regex);

Last line should return null but it returned 
["Edward", index: 6, input: "He is Edward's father.", groups: undefined]